# Successfully built pjsua for android, how to proceed?

Tags: android, pjsip

I have successfully built the pjsua sample app for android... however, there is no telling on how to proceed next... is there any helpful tutorial on how to use the sample app as a base for SIP calling?!

Answer (score 1):

[Follow the document](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#pjsua) there're 2 pjsua sample app you can install onto the device.

After running the first one, the screen will tell you to telnet into it like:

```
$ telnet 192.168.x.x 3388
```

Then you should see cmd list like this:

```
-> % telnet 192.168.3.8 2323
Trying 192.168.3.8...
Connected to 192.168.3.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
localhost> 
        ^
log       Change log level
exit      Exit session
call      Call related commands
im        IM and Presence Commands
acc       Account commands
audio     Conference and Media commands
stat      Status and config commands
sleep     Suspend keyboard input
network   Detect network type
shutdown  Shutdown application
restart   Restart application
```

Then you should be able to start add account to whatever signalling server you got. Pelase refer to [this manual](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm#cmd_call)

I got a list here for you to check:
1. Set up a signalling server like kamailio
2. Set up mysql on it for kamailio to use
3. Use kamctl to add account
4. Register that account from the telnet
5. Try to call another peer with call new sip:[ANOTHER_PEER]@[ANOTHER_PEER_IP]

Hope this help!